# How are the total possible trophies awarded determined?

Tags: clash-of-clans

While searching for an opponent, I have noticed that the total possible trophies to be awarded fluctuates.  I have seen enemies with 2 town halls greater than mine (and with xbows & flame towers) and the possible awarded trophies (if you 100%) is around 10 to 15.  What is this reason that this is so low?

[image]

*The most I have seen is around 35 possible trophies - when performing an attack that isn't revenge.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SuperCell, the game's creator, has provided [this resource](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/97-Trophies-Matchmaking-explained!) for those curious about matchmaking and how trophies work.

To summarize, it is completely dependent on your number of trophies in relation to your opponent's. If your opponent has significantly more trophies than you, you will gain a lot more trophies than usual if you win offensively or defensively. The opposite also applies, where if you lose an attack or defense against someone with less trophies than you, you will lose more trophies.

Level of town hall or any other building has no part in the calculation.

Comment: The above trophy description is not correct. I lose 35 trophies to someone that has more trophies than I do and they are a TH level higher. This may be their explanation, but the matching does not work that way. In last 5 attacks, all at an average the same number of trophies, around 3200, I have lost 141 trophies. I rarely ever come across that kind of numbers when I am searching. maybe I am not patient enough, but if that is the way they say it is supposed to work, then their Artificial intelligence needs fixing because that is not the way it works in real gaming. there must be some other fa

Comment: Yea, not buying that explanation .. Always getting attacked by people in same league or above usually a th level higher and lose -30 plus trophies for a 3 star loss defense. Meanwhile I am only seeing rewards of 7-11 trophies for a 3 star attack. I think if you are attacking below your th level you should get 1 trophy for it and a SEVERE loot penalty. The game needs some more balance.

Comment: @AK: There already is a loot penalty for attacking a lower level town hall base than yourself. But trophies earned are only dependent on the difference between the trophy amounts of both players.

Answer (score 1):

Available trophies is related to the difference between your trophies and your opponent's trophies, If your trophies is higher than your opponents, you will get low trophies.

Imagine you are in silver 1 and you attack someone then you go way up to gold 1 , If that person revenge you while you are in gold 1 he will get around 45 trophies. and if you revenge someone in silver you will get 0 trophies.