# How is it calculated how many trophies are won at end of match?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How is it calculated how many trophies an attacker wins (or looses) at the end of the match? I ask because I'm wondering does it ever make sense to "end battle" early, or is it better to let all deployed troops to destroy as much as possible to increase the trophies count?

For example I've seen people end games when only giants are remaining and they end the battle because giants can't attack the resources. Does this logic make sense or should they let the giants takeout as much defense as possible to increase bonus and trophy count?

Comment: What the body of your question is asking is entirely dependent on what the attacker's goal is. Some people care about trophies, but I'd argue that most raiding attacks are done to take as many as resources as possible. So, trophies are mostly inconsequential to players launching that kind of attack.

Comment: @Ellesedil yea but if you already have the troops out on the field and don't need to do anything, why wouldn't you want the trophies?

Comment: Because giants do very little damage and take a long time to kill. If you want to earn resources efficiently, you'll want to leave the battle, replenish your troops, and launch another attack on a resource-rich base as soon as you can. Trying to get one extra star so you can get 5 extra trophies isn't really worth the time to most.

Comment: For what it's worth, staying in the battle with just giants only really makes sense to me if you've only done around 45-49% total damage so far. Getting to 50% will make your attack successful, and grant you bonus resources. If you also destroyed the town hall previously, then you get an extra star (and twice the trophies), but that's about it. Not really worth the time investment unless you're *really* close to 50%.

Comment: @Ellesedil so if giants destroy another %3 that wouldn't increase trophy count? That is the question...

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're precisely asking. I'll build an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, this [answer for *How are the total possible trophies awarded determined?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168715/68492) is closely related. But it's missing a detail that I think you're actually trying to ask.

You are awarded a portion of the available trophies based on the number of stars you earn during the battle. You earn 1 star for destroying the Town Hall of the base, 1 star for destroying 50% of the base, and 1 more star for destroying 100% of the base.

So, let's say you've launched a raiding attack on a resource-rich base that is worth 30 total trophies. This means you'll get 10 trophies for each star you earn. You've snagged all of the resources you are interested in and you're open to ending the attack early. You've dealt 46% base damage so far. If you stay in the attack a bit longer and do only 3% extra damage, then you'll not earn any additional stars at only 49%, so you won't earn any extra trophies. If you do 4% extra damage instead, then you'll reach 50% damage done, which is an extra star and you'll earn 10 trophies.

Situationally, this probably depends if you've already destroyed the Town Hall or not. If you've destroyed the Town Hall already, then you've already earned 1 star and completed a successful attack. So, you'll earn the successful attack resource bonus for the league you're in and the extra trophies you'd earn aren't really a big deal. If I've yet to earn any stars, I'll usually let the attack ride on the off-chance that I can reach 50% and earn the bonus resources.

### But, is there a reason why some would want to actively avoid earning more trophies?

Yes there is. Many long-time players target certain leagues to be in for either raiding or resource defending purposes. Certain Town Hall levels will prefer to be placed in certain leagues in order to see more desirable bases to attack, or be in a pool of players that could do little damage in an attack. If you're earning extra trophies that you don't really want, then you'd have to launch attacks just to purposely lose and shed trophies to keep your spot in your preferred league. Or, you could just avoid earning trophies you don't really need.

Comment: Another related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/159504/68492

Comment: Does this not effect the loot bonus either?

Comment: @Celeritas: It could, but that's again based on destruction thresholds from what I understand. However, I'm not finding great sources to define the various thresholds so I'm going to hold off on editing the answer until I can find some.